# Can we create copy of catalog->mange product grid in custom module with some additional column

Tags: magento-1.9, product, grid

Can we create  copy of existing catalog -> manage product grid in custom module and extends its functionality add some new column, remove some existing column.
Both manage product grid and copy of manage product grid will use same table in back end. This is for magento 1.9

If it is possible please give me some guideline.

Comment: You can give this extension a try ... https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids/tree/1.0.0-wip. It let you customize most of magentos grids.

Comment: @sv3n this extension is already installed. I want catalog->manage product grid and copy of manage product grid in catalog->manage product prices further i want to customize manage product price grid in a way that it will not effect on original manage product grid.